# Split a string based on colon and new line and add the result to dicitonary

Tags: python, python-3.x

I want to convert the below unicode in python to a dictionary:

```
Version: 67
Build Number: 123master
Project Name: git+ssh://git@stash.xyz.com:1999/ns/x-y.git
Git Url: origin/master
Git Branch: 0223445as5njn34nfk6kg
perforce_url:
  //project//url//
artifacts:
  "./": "./"
exclude:
  - manifest.yml
  - node_modules
  - RPMS
  - .git
  - build-toolbox
```

```
>>> x
' Version: 67\nBuild Number: 123master\nProject Name: git+ssh://git@stash.xyz.com:1999/ns/x-y.git\nGit Url: origin/master\nGit Branch: 0223445as5njn34nfk6kg\nperforce_url:\n  //project//url//\nartifacts:\n  "./": "./"\nexclude:\n  - manifest.yml\n  - node_modules\n  - RPMS\n  - .git\n  - build-toolbox '
>>>
>>>
>>> dict(map(lambda x: x.split(':'), x.splitlines()))
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
ValueError: dictionary update sequence element #2 has length 4; 2 is required
```

```
dict(item.split(":") for item in x.splitlines())
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
ValueError: dictionary update sequence element #2 has length 4; 2 is required
```

I believe the problem is with the following item

```
Project Name: git+ssh://git@stash.xyz.com:1999/ns/x-y.git
```

git url above has a `:` in it.  Consequently, when I try to split, I get the following error:

ValueError: dictionary update sequence element #2 has length 4; 2 is required

```
dict(item.split(":") for item in data.splitlines())
```

```
dict(map(lambda x: x.split(':'), x.splitlines()))
```

expected result:

```
{"version" : 67 , " Build Number" : "123master", "Project Name": "xyz", "Git Url" : "origin/master", "Git Branch": "0223445as5njn34nfk6kg", "perforce_url":
  "//project//url//", "artifacts" : " "./": "./" "}
```

Actual result:

```
ValueError: dictionary update sequence element #2 has length 4; 2 is required
```

Comment: This seems to be [yaml](https://yaml.org) What is the reason for not using a parser there?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your immediate problem IS that colon- you can solve that by using `line.split(':', 1)`

You are also going to have problems with the list elements. Is the input file yaml by any chance?

```
import yaml

data = """
Version: 67
Build Number: 123master
Project Name: git+ssh://git@stash.xyz.com:1999/ns/x-y.git
Git Url: origin/master
Git Branch: 0223445as5njn34nfk6kg
perforce_url:
  //project//url//
artifacts:
  "./": "./"
exclude:
  - manifest.yml
  - node_modules
  - RPMS
  - .git
  - build-toolbox
"""
yaml.load(data)
```

Answer (score 1):

You could write your own parser (`yaml` like):

```
from parsimonious.grammar import Grammar
from parsimonious.nodes import NodeVisitor

data = """
Version: 67
Build Number: 123master
Project Name: git+ssh://git@stash.xyz.com:1999/ns/x-y.git
Git Url: origin/master
Git Branch: 0223445as5njn34nfk6kg
perforce_url:
  //project//url//
artifacts:
  "./": "./"
exclude:
  - manifest.yml
  - node_modules
  - RPMS
  - .git
  - build-toolbox 

"""

grammar = Grammar(
    r"""
    entries     = (item / list / ws)+

    item        = key equal ws* (!listsep value) newline?

    list        = listkey listitem+
    listkey     = key equal hs* newline
    listitem    = hs* listsep hs* value newline?

    key         = ~"^[^:]+"m
    equal       = ":"
    listsep     = "-"
    value       = ~".+"

    ws          = (hs / newline)+
    newline     = ~"[\r\n]"
    hs          = ~"[\t ]+"
    """
)

tree = grammar.parse(data)

class YAMLVisitor(NodeVisitor):
    def generic_visit(self, node, visited_children):
        return visited_children or node

    def visit_key(self, node, visited_children):
        return node.text.strip()

    def visit_value(self, node, visited_children):
        return node.text.strip()

    def visit_listkey(self, node, visited_children):
        key, *_ = visited_children
        return key

    def visit_listitem(self, node, visited_children):
        *_, value, _ = visited_children
        return value

    def visit_list(self, node, visited_children):
        key, values = visited_children
        return (key, values)

    def visit_item(self, node, visited_children):
        key, *_, lst, nl = visited_children
        value = lst[1]
        return (key, value)

    def visit_entries(self, node, visited_children):
        output = dict([child[0] for child in visited_children if isinstance(child[0], tuple)])
        return output


yaml = YAMLVisitor()
output = yaml.visit(tree)
print(output)
```

---

This would yield

```
{'Version': '67', 'Build Number': '123master', 'Project Name': 'git+ssh://git@stash.xyz.com:1999/ns/x-y.git', 'Git Url': 'origin/master', 'Git Branch': '0223445as5njn34nfk6kg', 'perforce_url': '//project//url//', 'artifacts': '"./": "./"', 'exclude': ['manifest.yml', 'node_modules', 'RPMS', '.git', 'build-toolbox']}
```